# Community ad ideas for ELL

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In order to promote this site, I created a community promotion ad to be placed on related Stack Exchange sites:

[image: English Language Learners Beta]

In a comment on [EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3571/31547), [Hugo](/users/35/) said:

> It would be good to include some blurb to encourage English language learners to click and ask their (ELL-appropriate) question there. I don't know what, though.

Do people have other ideas for ads or ideas for the blurb that Hugo suggested? Post them here so people can vote on them. If you have multiple ideas, please post only one idea per answer.

Additionally, I should probably note that the ads must be exactly 220x250 pixels, `.png` or `.gif`, and cannot be animated.

Comment: See also [What should our logo and site design look like](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/9/94).

Answer (score 8):

Here's another ad design we could use:

[image]

Incidentally, because these proposals are all part of an ad campaign, there's no reason we couldn't use more than one, I don't believe. In other words, I'm not competing against any of these other designs.

Answer (score 6):

ctype.h, I like your design, but that graphic looks rather pixelated. I took the liberty of drafting up a similar image; I hope you don't mind:

[image]

Comment: I like the colour...people will notice it more. But can we also put some encouraging motto there? Like: _Afraid to ask here? try ELL_ /or/ _looking for something more basic? try ELL_ :D (I know by myself that I did not feel comfortable on ELU since the **community there is quite sophisticated**)

Comment: @MasterPJ: Great idea; my main goal here was to maintain faithfulness to the original design, since I was using someone else's work.

Comment: @J.R. Could you post these separately so people can vote for each ad individually? By the way, I don't care if you improve my original design; it was just an idea. I'm not completely happy with my original design, but I thought it was a good start.

Comment: @ctype.h: Good suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 2):

This is the original beta ad that was posted on [EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3571/31547). I am posting it here so people can vote on it, even though it is also in the question.

[image: English Language Learners Beta]